# Zoom in like Mac does

Tags: settings, keyboard-shortcuts

Looking at the keyboard shortcuts, there is a zoom in and out but when I hit the keys specified, nothing happens. Do I have to install an app for these to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking at the <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> keyboard shortcuts? These allow you to zoom the text size in a specific application. (On macOS, zooming in the browser, Terminal, etc. works similarly.)

If you're looking to scale all text on the screen, there's an option to do that in System Settings --> Universal Access.

If you're looking more for something like the ["zoom content on the screen"](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH11488?locale=en_US) feature in macOS, you could try an app such as [xzoom](https://askubuntu.com/a/534573/486628).

Comment: In browser I'd recommend Super+mouse wheel and Super+0 to reset to default settings.

Comment: I am not talking about browser. On my mac I could hold the command key and scroll and it would zoom in to where my cursor is

Comment: That feature doesn't come with elementary, but xzoom provides something very similar.